# Swift UI AsyncImage error - Cannot call value of non-function type 'module<AsyncImage>'

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am learning SwiftUI, from scratch and trying to show a Image from a URL, I am using the built in AsyncImage method, yet I get this error with no context.
`Cannot call value of non-function type 'module<AsyncImage>'`, Googling didn't help and I am following the exact same code line-by-line from a article I am [following](https://www.appcoda.com/asyncimage/).[image].

Here's some more details from the diagnostics popup, I received.

> cannot call value of non-function type 'module'
>
> ---
>
> SchemeBuildError: Failed to build the scheme "AsyncImage"
>
> cannot call value of non-function type 'module'
>
> Compile ContentView.swift (x86_64):
> /Users/fayaz/Learn/AsyncImage/AsyncImage/ContentView.swift:14:9:
> error: cannot call value of non-function type 'module'
> AsyncImage(url: URL(string: imageUrl))
> ^

**Here's my setup.**

1. Macos BigSur v11.0.1
2. Xcode Version 12.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your project seems to be called `AsyncImage`, so without knowing all the other objects in your project its hard to know whether there would be some naming conflict.

However, your main issue is that [AsyncImage is iOS 15+](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/asyncimage). That means currently, your version of Xcode (you said 12.5) doesn't support it. You would need to [install Xcode 13](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) for the latest API. That would however require an Apple Developer account (can't remember whether the free version allows access to beta software though).

Comment: Thank you, didn't knew this method is an ios 15 feature, surprisingly didn't see this anywhere, or I missed it.

Comment: No worries, it honestly happens more often than you'd think, especially if you're new in the community and started with the latest and nicest features :)

Comment: The real issue is that the project is called `AsyncImage`, which creates a module with the same name that the compiler tries to use, that's why the error says `cannot call value of non-function type 'module'`. Solution is to rename the project.